# Image alt control source

Tags: vba, image, ms-access

I'm working on an Access document and came up with a little problem. A few details about the document forst:

- A few people have access to the document over fileshare, so I split the document into user interface and database for the ability of simultaneous edits
- I have over 100 items each with a differet image, with new ones being added twice a week
- images are stored separately in a local folder (together with user interface part of the database) and displayed on a form using Image object with Control Source attribute
- When new images are added, everyone has to sort through 100+ images to find the new ones and copy them into their respective local folder, which is somewhat annoying
- I prefer to store images on a local folder to increase loading speed so users don't have to "download" the image each time they display a specific item on the form.

Now the Control Source code for linking the images (using expression builder) is as follows:

```
=[Forms]![Items]![Settings]![ImageFolder] & [Ident] & ".png"
```

...with [Items] as the main form, [Settings] as subform, [ImageFolder] as an input field on the subform and [Ident] as an input field on the main form.
The reason for having a somewhat "complicated" way to link images is to avoid having duplicate data since I use both [ImageFolder] and [Ident] fields in other parts of my document as well.

**QUESTION**

Is it possible to use alternative paths for images?

The idea is to try loading an image from a local forlder - if it exists - if not, load an image from fileshare instead.

Comment: As an aside - instead of sorting through the images to find the new ones why not just try to copy the whole lot. If files already exist you get an option to skip them so only the new ones are processed, without the user having to select them individually

Comment: Other alternative - put something in your UI layer that checks for new images and copies  them locally

Comment: Trying to simplify as much as possible for users, as some of them are not exactly tech-savvy.
Any suggestions on how to check for new images and copying them? Didn't know ms access can do that...

Comment: Nitpicky point: Access file is not a "document" - it is a database. With the Access application you build a database application.

Comment: VBA could loop through shared folder items and check if each is in user's local folder. Looping folder items is a common topic. So is copying files. Access has intrinsic copy command `FileCopy` and then there is FileSystemObject `CopyFile`. Use Dir() method to check if file exists in local folder. As is, your question is too broad and lacks effort to solve issue - there is no code to analyze. Do research and when you have code with specific issue, ask question. Yes, could load alternate image with IIf() expression in ControlSource or even reference a VBA user function.